# How does salloc --exclusive behave on a crowded cluster?

Tags: slurm

In case of `salloc --exclusive`, the [slurm man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/salloc.html) is quite optimistic that it will find a node that is empty enough to grant exclusive access to the submitter.

What happens, though, if this is not the case, i. e. all the nodes have some load on them? Does it deny the request? (I can't be bothered to test this in a live environment.)

My idea is to have a command that behaves like `salloc --exclusive` when there are free nodes ready for exclusive access, but is robust enough to not fail at crowded times, but then redirect me to a mixed-state node (ideally selecting with as low a load as possible, in the manner of `SelectTypeParameters=CR_LLN`, but messing around with the scheduler is not an option).